# Instant App module searches for resources in another not base module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-apps

I'm developing an Instant App, that has `base` module and 2 feature modules: `feature1` and `feature2`. I'm getting strange crash when I'm trying to launch `feature2` activity:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.myapp.qa/com.test.myapp.feature2.ui.activity.Feature2Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class android.widget.ProgressBar
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class android.widget.ProgressBar
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class android.widget.ProgressBar
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:650)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:723)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:791)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                                at com.test.myapp.ui.activity.base.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:237)
                                                                                at com.test.myapp.feature2.ui.activity.Feature2Activity.onCreate(Feature2Activity.java:123)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                             Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.test.myapp.qa:layout/random_feature1_layout with resource ID #0x82030011
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/random_feature1_layout_fns.xml from drawable resource ID #0x82030011
                                                                                at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:754)
                                                                                at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:598)
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:885)
                                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:953)
                                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
                                                                                at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:281)
                                                                                at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:230)
                                                                                at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:226)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:650)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:723)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:791)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                                at com.test.myapp.ui.activity.base.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:237)
                                                                                at com.test.myapp.feature2.ui.activity.Feature2Activity.onCreate(Feature2Activity.java:123)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Class not found LinearLayout
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:220)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:139)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1254)
                                                                                at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:744)
                                                                                at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:598) 
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:885) 
                                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:953) 
                                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928) 
                                                                                at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:281) 
                                                                                at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:230) 
                                                                                at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:226) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:650) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:723) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:791) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
                                                                                at com.test.myapp.ui.activity.base.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:237) 
                                                                                at com.test.myapp.feature2.ui.activity.Feature2Activity.onCreate(Feature2Activity.java:123) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
    06-18 10:42:37.616 11607-11607/com.test.myapp.qa E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "LinearLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.myapp.qa-ncO99Ptagbu_PYoBeZhFeA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.myapp.qa-ncO99Ptagbu_PYoBeZhFeA==/split_feature2.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.myapp.qa-ncO99Ptagbu_PYoBeZhFeA==/split_feature1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.myapp.qa-ncO99Ptagbu_PYoBeZhFeA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
                                                                                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:201)
                                                                                    ... 47
```

If we look at `Feature2Activity` layout file, line 76 we'll see:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress" />
```

Drawable `progress.xml` is located in `feature2` resources. If we remove it, or change it to some drawable from `base` resources, everything works fine.

Another strange thing is this line:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.test.myapp.qa:layout/random_feature1_layout with resource ID #0x82030011
```

Layout `random_feature1_layout` is located at `feature1` resources, and shouldn't be referenced at all. But if we go to `feature2\R.java` file, and look for `progress.xml` drawable we'll find:

```
public static final int progress=0x80030011;
```

And if you look closer you'll notice that `progress`'s and `random_feature1_layout`'s ids are differ by one digit: `0x80030011` and `0x82030011`. So I made an assumption, that `feature2` for unknown reasons looks for `progress` drawable in `feature1` resources. I tried to remove `feature1` dependency and crash disappeared, that confirms my assumption.

I should also note that this issue is observed only for Instant app. Installed app works fine.

My question is how is it possible that `feature2` searches for resources in `feature1` apk? Do you have any ideas what caused this behaviour or maybe hints how to debug this issue?

Comment: Is the same resource or a resource with the same name also available in feature1 split?

Comment: @MaruAhues no, it is just some random resource with similar id, it's not even a drawable.

Comment: I'm encountering a very similar problem. I submittted a bug report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62899015

Comment: and found out another tracker here (it is probably the same issue): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62852384

Comment: @gbaccetta Yeah, that's reported by me :)

Comment: @mol yep I added a comment to mark mine as duplicate. Did you find any workaround?

Comment: @gbaccetta No, I postponed development until more stable version is released.

Comment: @mol bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62899015 was reported as an intended behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to  [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62852384), it has been fixed with Android SDK Built-Tools to 27.0.2 
Please update your **Android SDK Built-Tools to 27.0.2**
And ensure you are on **Android Studio 3.0.1 or newer**.

If any issue persists, please report [at Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62852384) they will re-open to examine. Thanks!