# How to force android project to merge the resources from feature module?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-apps

I have a ***multi-module*** project with ***base-feature*** and ***feature modules***.

The problem is that after the build the resources from ***feature module*** are duplicated with a second `id` and the resources are not merged properly in the end. Is there a something about the *gradle plugin* which should be done to make this run? ==> `com.android.feature`

When I run the project it tries to find the resource from feature module with the feature module resource `id`, but in the end the ***main module*** has the same resource already with another `id`, which I guess should be merged.

Comment: it is probably related to the same issue described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614343
There is a tracker we opened here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62852384. Please star it if you consider it is the same problem:

Answer (score 2):

This is an intended behavior. Please make sure that your resource IDs are unique. Refer to this Android Instant Apps FAQ: “Can I share resources between features?”

https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html#project-structure

> However, you must keep the IDs for your resources unique between your
>   dependent features and base feature. For example, if your base feature
>   provides a resource with the ID R.id.feature_layout and a dependent
>   feature defines another resource with the same ID, the instant app
>   uses the resource from the base feature instead of the dependent
>   feature.

Comment: Trying to use the resource from another module or from base is fine, but not finding the resource in feature module from the same feature module, seems to me not right.  In a small sample project it is fine, but in a big projects it seems the resource processing is not successful.

Comment: By the way I was speaking about the generated integer IDs, but not the names.

Comment: I am not sure if your issue is the same as gbaccetta’s (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62852384), but if it is, could you add to it with your reproducible project? Otherwise, please file a new one, then link to it back in here, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787